# Commit multiple SVN repositories using a Python script?

Tags: python, svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I've been doing a lot of script-powered mass-updates to dozens of project folders at once, lately. Unfortunately, my pointy-haired boss insists that each folder be committed to TortoiseSVN separately after one of these bulk edits - he wants every folder to have a different revision number. Me being the automation fiend that I am, turned to scripting to try to solve this problem for me. This is what I'm trying:

```
import subprocess
import glob

for filepath in glob.glob("C:\eForms\*"):
    if ".svn" not in filepath:
        subprocess.call(['svn commit',filepath, '--message "<commit message here>"'], shell=True)
```

When I try to run it, I get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Any ideas?

EDIT: Think I solved that issue. I tweaked the syntax, so now the call line reads `subprocess.call(["svn", "commit",('"',filepath,'"'), '-m "<commit message>"'], shell=True)`

Now I'm getting the error `svn: E020024: Error resolving case of '"<filepath>"'`

EDIT2: And pulling the quotes off the filepath solved that. All working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax of the call function turned out to be

```
subprocess.call(["svn", "commit", filepath, '-m "<commit message here>"'], shell = True)
```

Comment: it appears that you have solved this question. In your code it says "if ".svn" not in filepath:". How does this work? I am trying to commit files through python also.

Comment: This was 6 years ago now and I haven't used svn since, so I don't remember exactly what I was doing. I assume there was a "something.svn" file or  folder in the directory that I didn't want to commit, though. maybe ".svn" is subversion's config directory, akin to ".git"?